# JSF 2.0 AJAX Calls Failing

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets

I am working on a project to take an existing project using JSF1.2, JSP, Struts, Tiles, Richfaces ... to simply use JSF2.0, the built-in facelets support, and updating Richfaces to version 4.

So far things are going pretty well, except for one major road block. I am trying to update AJAX components that were previously being handled with the `<a4j:support>` tags, to the `<f:ajax>` tags and instead of working how I'd hope, I'm getting an error which I can only interpret as me having forgotten something in terms of configuring everything.

It's a NullPointerException being thrown in com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter() method.

When I load the page the first time, I can see in the debugger the component binding correctly to the backing value; the page loads without incident. It's when I try to activate the AJAX event on said component that it blows up. I get an error, and nothing updated via AJAX. It's happening with every AJAX component I try to convert. Here is one such example:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu
        value="#{userSession.selectedNetwork}"
        id="network"
        >
        <f:selectItems value="#{userSession.networkUIOptions}" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="selectedStation edit_site_button add_site_button"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the bean I'm referencing in that code is now annotated ala JSF2.0 and removed from faces-config.xml, however, I haven't completely gotten rid of faces-config.xml. Still working on converting everything. Also, I'm running this on Tomcat 6.0.

Any help, suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm really stuck on this problem.

EDIT 1:

Using mojarra version 2.1.1 as per the bundle title I downloaded. Having trouble getting exact stack trace. Logging doesn't seem to be working correctly after changing so many things. Will keep trying. Also will try simple page and report results.

EDIT 2:
So, trying to 'minimal' page yielded the same results, same error.

Still couldn't get logging to work exactly right, so just did some ghetto logging. See below for something resembling a proper stack trace:

EDIT 3:
Okay, updated ghetto stack trace with line numbers. You guessed right on the line number in the first class to toss the error:
http://pastebin.com/49yUDcPM

doFilter function of NPNSessionFilter.java:
http://pastebin.com/iwG0rcQ6

test page I created for BalusC's at suggestion:
http://pastebin.com/kSeUyj7g

EDIT 4:

http://tinypic.com/r/2dca0yo/7
http://tinypic.com/r/16jet7s/7

Here are images of the libs currently packaged in the WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder. Previous programmer included a lot of junk that I haven't cleaned out yet. Likewise, not sure where struts JARs are coming from. Deleted any pre-dist JARs I could find relating to strusts or tiles.

EDIT 5:

Okay, breakthrough! This comment made a world of difference "Likewise, not sure where struts JARs are coming from. Deleted any pre-dist JARs I could find relating to strusts or tiles."

Cleaned ear, re-dist, and things work better now. Obviously it wasn't just some lib I forgot to remove, but a lib I forgot to remove, and then clean the EAR out after having removed. AJAX requests are now properly going through, and I can see in the debugger values being re-bound as the request comes through! Load of other problems, but can manage those in my own time. BalusC, you led me to this solution; if you want to submit an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Mentioning exact Mojarra version and the full stacktrace may be helpful. Does this error also occur when you create a minimalistic page with a very simple ajax form something like `<h:form><h:inputText value="#{sessionScope.input}"><f:ajax event="keyup" render="output"/></h:inputText><h:outputText id="output" value="#{sessionScope.input}"/></h:form>` without a backing bean?

Comment: @BalusC Updated best as possible. Will get back to you with minimal page.

Comment: @BalusC: Now updated with most of the details you asked for.

Comment: Hm, that's an odd trace. Where are the line numbers? The line number where this exception occurred is fairly imporant to know. Anyway, after looking at Mojarra 2.1.1 source, my best guess would be line 442. What exactly is the `NPNSessionFilter` doing? When you tested the minimal code example, did you leave all the tiles/richfaces/struts tags out the Facelets page?

Comment: @BalusC: Updated with pastebins to relevant NPNSessionFilter code, updated stack trace w/ line numbers, and test page markup. Also, the main purpose of NPNSessionFilter is to run some custom access control code on each request, but also, it tends to catch ANY rogue errors that occur in the application, hence the reason I'm able to catch the error there. Also FYI, I attempted to update to Mojarra 2.1.2, but made no difference AFAICT. Also, tried the test page again w/o reference to richfaces, tomahawk, or trinidad. Same results, though.

Comment: I'm not sure. Line 441 does not exactly match the 2.1.1 source (or was yours a slight different build? I have the FCS). Anyway, line 442 suggests that the `FacesContext#getViewRoot()` returned `null`, however I don't immediately see any cause for this. Can you post a list of all libs you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`? Maybe that one of them is designed for JSF 1.x and thus causes all this trouble.

Comment: @BalusC: Please see latest update. Included screen shots of the WARs WEB-INF/lib folder. Some disclaimers in the update. Also used FCS build, but updated to 2.1.2, hence the difference in line #s. Also, thanks for taking the time to help with this problem. I am thoroughly stumped!

Comment: @BalusC: Please see update 5. You forced me to have a near-sighted revelation = )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl:PartialViewContextImpl.java:createPartialResponseWriter:441

This exception indicates that the JSF view root is null which in turn indicates among others that there's some JSF 1.2 targeted 3rd party or custom `ViewHandler` in the classpath which isn't doing its job entirely right for JSF 2.0 and thus needs to be upgrade as well (or removed altogether).

Based on your screenshot with the overview of all JARs, the `struts-faces` JAR is the main suspect. But those mixed versions of Apache Commons and JSTL libraries also doesn't look right.

Comment: In addition to the point @BalusC makes about removing unneeded libraries, the other lesson here is to be sure that you CLEAN your projects before building, when making substantial changes to the supporting libraries, underlying framework of your project. Otherwise those unwanted projects may linger around and cause headaches like mine.